# How to use ffmpeg for text and gif overlay together in android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

How to overlay text and gif together on video using ffmpeg.

I have used below command,

```
"-i", mSelectedPath, "-ignore_loop", "0", "-i", 
"watermark_gif.gif", "-filter_complex", 
"overlay=5:5:shortest=1:format=auto", "-codec:a", "copy", "-preset", "ultrafast", 
"a.mp4"});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the [drawtext filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ignore_loop 0 -i watermark.gif -filter_complex "overlay=5:5:shortest=1:format=auto,drawtext=text='Hello world':fontsize=20:fontcolor=white,format=yuv420p" -codec:a copy -preset ultrafast -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Comment: at first time getting error for this command which is for fontfile when I added fontfile it is working like charm, you save my day thankks!